# Open Javafx module to Gson module in Intellij

Tags: java, javafx, module, gson

Im trying to save a gamestate object as a Gson file in java, but i get the error `Unable to make field private final float javafx.scene.paint.Color.red accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene.paint" to module com.google.gson`

How do I open the module to Gson?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to explicitly open the module when you run the program on the command line with the `—add-opens`flag.

Eg add the following to the command line options:

```
—add-opens javafx.graphics=com.google.gson
```

Comment: Where would i put that line in IntelliJ? In the module-info?

Comment: The error message is then: Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package javafx.scene.paint not found in module.